# Pgfplots 3D patch plot: coloring the facet border before patch refine, without losing depth buffer

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, transparency, blend-mode

I think I might be stretching PGFPlots a little here, but I would like to give a solid color to the facet border of a patch plot. However, `patch refines` must be active, otherwise the colormap is not sampled sufficiently; at the same time, I want to color the facet border of the original mesh, not of the refined mesh. Also, I do not want to lose the depth buffer: I want segments "behind" facets to not be visible. An image:

[image: Different rendering modes]

**(a)** `shader=faceted interp` together with `patch refines=3` produces those unwanted lines on the refined faces

**(b)** Disabling `patch refines` displays the correct facet border, but now the gradient is sampled only at the vertices and we lose the color blue.

**(c)** Using two different `\addplot3` commands (one with `patch` and one with `mesh`) is also not working, the `mesh` command does not use the depth buffer, so I see hidden lines.

**(d)** Desired result. For this one, I used a patch with refines, followed by another patch with black facet border and white facet fill, and then I blended the two in a `blend group=multiply`. The white fill clips the hidden part of the facet borders (it needs to be wrapped in a transparency group).

**This works fine on a display, but unsurprisingly printers (and several editors/viewers) don't really like it:** the result is overprinted and the color is extremely dark, or you can see the facet subdivisions, or you lose the blend group and the facet color is white.

**What can I do to obtain (d) without having to use a `transparency group` and a `blend group` (or using more conventional PDF features)?**

My knowledge of TeX is not sufficient to understand the internals of PGFPlots. Here is an MVE for the picture above:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{filecontents}{model.dat}
  -1 -1 0
  1 -1 0
  0 0 0.3

  1 -1 0
  1 1 0
  0 0 0.3

  -1 -1 0
  -1 1 0
  0 0 0.3

  1 1 0
  -1 1 0
  0 0 0.3
\end{filecontents}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colormap/cool, title={(a)}]
      % Gradient is fine, but facet boundary is ugly
      \addplot3 [patch, shader=faceted interp, faceted color=black, patch refines=3] file {model.dat};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colormap/cool, title={(b)}]
      % Facet boundary is correct, but gradient is subsampled
      \addplot3 [patch, shader=faceted interp, faceted color=black] file {model.dat};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colormap/cool, title={(c)}]
      % Depth is lost
      \addplot3 [patch, shader=interp, patch refines=3] file {model.dat};
      \addplot3 [patch, mesh, draw=black] file {model.dat};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colormap/cool, title={(d)}]
      % What I came up with does not print correctly. I want to blend multiply the two plots, forcing
      % the facet color to white so it does not mask the gradient underneath it
      \begin{scope}[blend group=multiply]
        % This one brings the color:
        \addplot3 [patch, shader=interp, patch refines=3] file {model.dat};
        % If I don't explicitly set the transparecy group, we can see through the model
        \begin{scope}[transparency group]
          % This one brings the border
          \addplot3 [patch, shader=faceted, faceted color=black, fill=white] file {model.dat};
        \end{scope}
      \end{scope}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: you change patch coordinate order mid your date, which gives a wrong mesh - see your figure (c).

Comment: Thanks, I updated the picture and the code. In fact, I intended to use `patch` and `mesh` simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `tikzfadingfrompicture` like this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{model.dat}
-1 -1 0
1 -1 0
0 0 0.3

1 -1 0
1 1 0
0 0 0.3

1 1 0
-1 1 0
0 0 0.3

-1 1 0
-1 -1 0
0 0 0.3
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=none]
\addplot3[patch, shader=faceted, faceted color=transparent!0, fill=transparent!100] file{model.dat};
\end{axis}
\path (0,0) circle[radius=10]; %encompassing circle for alignment
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colormap/cool]
\addplot3[patch, shader=interp, patch refines=3] file{model.dat};
\end{axis}
\fill[path fading=myfading, fit fading=false] (0,0) rectangle (7,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D pyramid with shaded sides and lines]

Comment: Worked perfectly! One side note, it seems the printer in this case rasterizes the whole image, so I had to increase manually the rasterization resolution (or better, I flattened all transparencies with Acrobat DC)

Comment: I am not used to printing stuff myself, so I do not really know how it is handled or what is doable or what is good practice.